# Microsoft Interop Excel, List all the available Font styles in C# Vsto

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-addins

I am new in the .Net world. In an Addin for the Excel in am developing I wanted to list all the Font styles those are available in the Excel.
Could you please let me know if there are something as similar as Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbDimGrey(for colors) available to list all the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Office applications use the fonts installed in the operating system. The Excel here lists the fonts from Windows API. And hence the fonts are not available in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel rather in System.Drawing.Text. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-enumerate-installed-fonts).

```
using System.Drawing.Text;
InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();
FontFamily[] fontFamilies = installedFontCollection.Families;
```